# Pig - Flatten data bags

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a below data in apache pig

```
({(ABC,123,XYZ,{(1,2,3),(4,5,6)},QWE)})
```

and I want to extract specific fields, like my intended output will be

```
ABC, 123, 1, 2, 3
ABC, 123, 4, 5, 6
```

How we can do this using pig?

Comment: `out = foreach a generate name, age, flatten(TransposeTupleToBag(sno1, sno2, sno3))`; return error `2015-12-09 04:53:41,700 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 14, column 108>  mismatched input ')' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /mnt/var/log/pig/pig_1449634813944.log`

Answer (score 1):

I completed it myself with little bit of reading

```
out = foreach a generate FLATTEN($0);

out1 = foreach out generate $0, $1, flatten($3);
```